# Can "prognosis" ever be correctly used outside of the medical meaning of the word?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

i.e. would it be correct to ask about the 'prognosis' of an ongoing engineering project?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the use of the word in the context of an engineering project.  Certainly it is commonly used in that way.

Comment: All sorts of medical terms are used metaphorically. *The temperature of the meeting returned to normal, following fevered discussion between the separate organs of the business* But I was never one to mix my metaphors!

Comment: @WS2 It is fine once you get the hang over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This word is commonly associated with medicine but may be used in any context.  It means the act of predicting a result.  The prediction does not *have* to be skilled or correct.  In those cases we might be talking about [timeless omniscience](http://www.reasonablefaith.org/omniscience-tensed-facts-and-divine-eternity) or forms of [clairvoyance](http://madworldnews.com/psychic-prediction-obama-2016/).

In colloquial terms the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prognosis) of prognosis is pro *in advance* and gnosis *knowledge*: ‘knowing’ (as best we can) what the future holds.

Prognosis is generally regarded as being thought-through, as distinct from guessing.  The word is generally used in the sense of evidence-based and reasoned (if not certain) projection of events, and as such I have come across the idea quite often in systems analysis (e.g. [this US patent application](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150003220.pdf)).

Use of *prognosis* in non-medical contexts is just as permissible as using the related word *agnostic* (not-definitely-knowing) outside the religious discourses with which it is most commonly associated.

Comment: That 'gnosis' certainly stands out as a root word begging for a prefix! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnosis

Comment: @WayfaringStranger just don't cut off your Gnosis to spite your Fate.

Answer (score 5):

[Prognosis](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prognosis) can be used outside the context of medicine. In my experience, its usage in an engineering context is not uncommon, especially when a project is not going well

Comment: Someone on another shift always wrote that in his maintenance report for working on manufacturing equipment.  But I'm pretty sure he got it from Seinfeld "Prognosis Negative" movie they were going to go see.